# Detecting a circle in an image in MATLAB - works in the binary, but not on the original

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I wrote a code for detecting a circle in my image.

**Image.png   :-**
[image: Original Image]

**Code:-**

```
blueBall1 = imread('Image.png');
t = imtool(blueBall1);

close(t)

r = blueBall1(:, :, 1);
g = blueBall1(:, :, 2);
b = blueBall1(:, :, 3);

figure
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(r),title('R Plane')
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(g),title('G Plane')
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(b),title('B Plane')

justBlue = b - r/2 - g/2;

close all

bw = justBlue > 50;
imshow(bw);

ball1 = bwareaopen(bw, 30);
imshow(ball1);

Rmin=15;Rmax=50;  
[centersBright, radiiBright] = imfindcircles(ball1, [Rmin Rmax], ...
                                        'ObjectPolarity','bright','sensitivity',0.83)
hold on
viscircles(centersBright, radiiBright,'LineStyle','--');hold off

imshow(blueBall1),
hold on viscircles(centersBright, radiiBright,'LineStyle','--');hold off
```

If I make the last two lines like comments, it shows the binary picture where there is circle around the blue ball:

[image]

However, the last two lines are for the original image which loads but without the circle around the ball.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: So you're talking purely about *displaying* the image and `viscircles`?

Comment: Could you post the picture of the blue ball?

Comment: The original image can be seen here:
http://prikachi.com/images/492/8837492S.png
There are other blue parts, so I try detecting by colour and shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some figure commands and moved viscircles to a new line at the end and this is what I get as my final image out:

[image]

It is the original image with a circle around the blue ball. Is this what you are looking for?

Here's your code with a couple of changes:

```
blueBall1 = imread('ballimage.png');
t = imtool(blueBall1);

close(t)

r = blueBall1(:, :, 1);
g = blueBall1(:, :, 2);
b = blueBall1(:, :, 3);

figure;
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(r),title('R Plane')
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(g),title('G Plane')
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(b),title('B Plane')

justBlue = b - r/2 - g/2;

close all

figure;
bw = justBlue > 50;
imshow(bw);

figure;
ball1 = bwareaopen(bw, 30);
imshow(ball1);

Rmin=15;Rmax=50;  
[centersBright, radiiBright] = imfindcircles(ball1, [Rmin Rmax], ...
                                        'ObjectPolarity','bright','sensitivity',0.83)
hold on
viscircles(centersBright, radiiBright,'LineStyle','--');hold off

figure;
imshow(blueBall1),
hold on 
viscircles(centersBright, radiiBright,'LineStyle','--');hold off
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Consider marking this answer as correct.